# How to arrive in the US more than 10 days before my job starts?

Tags: h1-visa, esta

I have a job offer from a US company who will sponsor me for the H1B visa. The visa condition states than I cannot enter until 10 days before the start of my job. I have a family and will need more time to look for housing, organise ourselves, look at schools, rent a car etc.
Ideally my family and I would like to travel to the US as tourists about one month before my job start, entering under the WVP (ESTA), then take a two-day trip to Canada/Mexico 10 days before the job start and re-enter the US on our H1/H4 visas.

The H visas will be approved and stamped before we enter the US the first time as tourists. We will have a return ticket on our ESTA trip so as to comply with the rules but will not use the return if we are able to travel to Canada/Mexico and re-enter the US on our H-visas. 
Would this be possible? Are we violating any visa rules?

Thanks for helping

Kat